# Match json response to pattern in fixture file for testing with spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, fixtures

we've implemented fixture files for our API acceptance tests. It's working fine with requests. We're loading the file with the request and using it for the request in tests. However, I want to implement the same thing with responses. I want to validate that a parsed json response that we get matches the fixture file pattern. So far, I've tried this:
The fixture file fixtures/files/pauses/response.json:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
      },
    "type": "pause",
    "attributes": {
        "working_session_id": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "starts_at": {
          "type": "string"
          },
        "ends_at": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "start_signature_id": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "end_signature_id": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "secure_id": {
          "type": "integer"
          },
        "created_by": {
          "type": "integer"
          }
    }
},
"meta": {
    "git_commit": {
      "type": "string"
      }
}
```

This is part of the api test sending the update request in update_spec.rb

```
let(:response) { parsed_file_fixture("pauses/response.json") }

    example "Update a pause" do
      do_request(request)

      parsed_json = JSON.parse(response_body)

  
      assert_equal parsed_json, response    
      expect(status).to eq 200
    end
```

And then this is the error log when I run rspec

```
1) Pauses /api/v3/workspaces/:workspace_id/time_trackings/:time_tracking_id/pauses/:pause_id Update PATCH Update a pause Authenticated as admin Update a time tracking
 Failure/Error: assert_match parsed_json, response

 Minitest::Assertion:
   Expected {"data"=>{"id"=>"62", "type"=>"pause", "attributes"=>{"working_session_id"=>194, "starts_at"=>"2021-02-05T17:48:06+01:00", "ends_at"=>"2021-02-05T19:13:06+01:00", "created_at"=>"2021-02-05T19:43:19+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2021-02-05T19:43:20+01:00", "start_signature_id"=>nil, "end_signature_id"=>nil, "secure_id"=>"65389b5130cff0ab804cc9ff87f5fd5d", "created_by"=>"browser-stamps"}}, "meta"=>{"git_commit"=>"df02dfa12f70a823bbdcbc1c86ff2357c997d488"}} to match {"data"=>{"id"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "type"=>"pause", "attributes"=>{"working_session_id"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "starts_at"=>{"type"=>"string"}, "ends_at"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "created_at"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "updated_at"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "start_signature_id"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "end_signature_id"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "secure_id"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "created_by"=>{"type"=>"integer"}}}, "meta"=>{"git_commit"=>{"type"=>"string"}}}.
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to use fixture files that way and allow for non static values and just verify matching the type of attribute? Some of the attributes are randomly generated and differ every time, and the ids vary as well. That's why I can't use static values in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json_matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/json_matchers) gem to validate each response against a JSON schema. With JSON schema, you can define a structure for each response and have validations for each key and value. (Check out [Understanding JSON Schema](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/))

There are also JSON schema generators (see [this](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter)) which you can use to generate JSON schemas based on your existing responses to use with the `json_matchers` gem.